# How to save for offline access using flutter

Tags: flutter

Please is there how I can make my app save files and access offline

I don't want the download to be visible to the user in their device storage, but only accessible inside of the application. Like you download and save for offline use

If yes, anyone that can help will be appreciated please

Comment: You can achieve this by getting the application private directory. ```getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()```
Use this library : https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

Answer (score 0):

Use https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider with https://pub.dev/packages/hive . You can use hive to store and retrieve data synchronously.